# apply rename_if predicate to column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a set of excel spreadsheets which has column names which are dates.

After reading in the data with `readxl::read_xlsx()`, these column names become excel index dates (i.e. an integer representing days elapsed from `1899-12-30`)

Is it possible to used `dplyr::rename_if()` or similar to rename all column names that are currently integers? I have written a function `rename_func` that I would like to apply to all such columns.

`df %>% rename_if(is.numeric, rename_func)` is not suitable as `is.numeric` is applied to the data in the column not the column name itself. I have also tried:

```
is.name.numeric <- function(x) is.numeric(names(x))
df %>% rename_if(is.name.numeric, rename_func)
```

which does not work and does not change any names (i.e. `is.name.numeric` returns `FALSE` for all cols)

edit: here is a dummy version of my data

```
df_badnames <- structure(list(Level = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3), Title = c("AUSTRALIAN TOTAL", 
"MANAGERS", "Chief Executives, Managing Directors & Legislators", 
"Farmers and Farm Managers", "Hospitality, Retail and Service Managers"
), `38718` = c(213777.89, 20997.52, 501.81, 121.26, 4402.7), 
    `38749` = c(216274.12, 21316.05, 498.1, 119.3, 4468.67), 
    `38777` = c(218563.95, 21671.84, 494.08, 118.03, 4541.02), 
    `38808` = c(220065.05, 22011.76, 488.56, 116.24, 4609.28)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I would like:

```
df_goodnames <- structure(list(Level = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3), Title = c("AUSTRALIAN TOTAL", 
"MANAGERS", "Chief Executives, Managing Directors & Legislators", 
"Farmers and Farm Managers", "Hospitality, Retail and Service Managers"
), Jan2006 = c(213777.89, 20997.52, 501.81, 121.26, 4402.7), 
    Feb2006 = c(216274.12, 21316.05, 498.1, 119.3, 4468.67), 
    Mar2006 = c(218563.95, 21671.84, 494.08, 118.03, 4541.02), 
    Apr2006 = c(220065.05, 22011.76, 488.56, 116.24, 4609.28)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I understand that it is best practice to create a `date` column and change the shape of this df, but I need to join a few spreadsheets first and having integer column names causes a lot of problems. I currently have a work around but the crux of my question (apply a rename_if predicate to a name, rather than a column) is still interesting.

Comment: @RonakShah done, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although, the names look numeric but they are not

```
class(names(df_badnames))
#[1] "character"
```

so they would not be caught by `is.numeric` or similar other functions.

One way to do this is find out which `names` can be coerced to numeric and then convert them into the date format of our choice

```
cols <- as.numeric(names(df_badnames))
names(df_badnames)[!is.na(cols)] <- format(as.Date(cols[!is.na(cols)], 
                                          origin = "1899-12-30"), "%b%Y")

df_badnames

#  Level Title                                           Jan2006 Feb2006 Mar2006 Apr2006
#   <dbl> <chr>                                             <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1 AUSTRALIAN TOTAL                                213778. 216274. 218564. 220065.
#2     2 MANAGERS                                         20998.  21316.  21672.  22012.
#3     3 Chief Executives, Managing Directors & Legisla…    502.    498.    494.    489.
#4     3 Farmers and Farm Managers                          121.    119.    118.    116.
#5     3 Hospitality, Retail and Service Managers          4403.   4469.   4541.   4609.
```